# RecyclerView stutters while getting images from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

As seen below I compress the images before uploading to Firebase Storage. That part works perfectly compresses image from 10 Mb to 700-800Kb. I get the images from firestore with their downloadUrl's and show them in a recyclerview.That is where problem starts,RecyclerView stutters as you scroll while getting these images from firestore. I don't have this problem if i dont compress the images but at this time sizes are becoming larger and it tooks 7-8 seconds do download it so i must compress it or do it in another way that i do not know. So what should i do?

```
binding.saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(imageData !=null){
                UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
                String imageName = "images/"+uuid+".jpg";

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), imageData);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);

                byte[] imageInBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                storageReference.child(imageName).putBytes(imageInBytes).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        StorageReference newReference = firebaseStorage.getReference(imageName);

                        newReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                String title = binding.titleEditText.getText().toString();
                                String description = binding.descriptionEditText.getText().toString();
                                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                String email = user.getEmail();

                                HashMap<String,Object> postData = new HashMap<>();

                                postData.put("downloadUrl",downloadUrl);
                                postData.put("title",title);
                                postData.put("description",description);
                                postData.put("userEmail",email);
                                postData.put("date", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                                firebaseFirestore.collection("Throwbacks").add(postData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                                        NavDirections action = NewThrowbackFragmentDirections.actionNewThrowbackFragmentToFeedFragment();

                                        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action);

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                                });


                            }
                        });

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the getData code block:

```
private void getData(){
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Throwbacks").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("userEmail",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            if(error !=null){
                System.out.println(error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            if(value !=null){

                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value.getDocuments()){

                    Map<String,Object> data = snapshot.getData();

                    String userEmail = (String) data.get("userEmail");
                    String description = (String) data.get("description");
                    String downloadUrl = (String) data.get("downloadUrl");
                    String title = (String) data.get("title");

                    Throwback throwback = new Throwback(userEmail,description,downloadUrl,title);
                    throwbackArrayList.add(throwback);
                    memoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried not compressing the images, that works but in that way it took long time to get a image from firestore, so i need to compress it and show the images in recyclerview without suttering.